# Run time error - arcpy.xytoline

Tags: arcpy, runtimeerror

I have a point layer and i need to connect all the points(4046) with each other. I tried it through python console from Arcgis but it gives me run time error.
Here is my code :

```
    import arcpy
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("vertex_final",['POINT_X','POINT_Y'])
outlines= r"C:\Users\stelitsa\Desktop\descriptive_data"
i = 0
while (i<4064):
 X1=row[i]
 Y1=row[i+1]
 print  X1, Y1
   for row in cursor:
    X2=row[0]
    Y2= row[1]
    if X1!=X2:
      arcpy.XYToLine_management(cursor,outlines,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,"GEODESIC","id")
```

And here is the error :

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 13, in 
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3063, in XYToLine
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

This is the first time that I have used Python.

Comment: XYToLine wants fields, not values and I'm not sure you're accessing the values correctly either. Sorry, I don't know arcpy well ehough to help beyond that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a cursor object as in input for your arcpy tool, which isn't valid. I'd suggest trying something else. One method is to create a line feature class in the same spatial reference as your points. Then iterate through your points, iterate again in a nested loop, and create line geometries from your two XY's. Insert these geometries into your newly created feature class. All lines will be doubled up, so a `DeleteIdentical` will be needed to remove duplicates.

Try:

```py
import arcpy
import os

#point feature class path
pntFc = r"C:\GDB.gdb\TestPoints"
#output line feature class path
outLnFc = r"C:\GDB.gdb\OutLines"


#store points in set
pnts = set ()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (pntFc, "SHAPE@XY") as curs:
    for xy, in curs:
        pnts.add (xy)

#get spatial reference from point feature class
sr = arcpy.Describe (pntFc).spatialReference

#create line feature class
outPath, outName = os.path.split (outLnFc)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (outPath, outName, "POLYLINE", spatial_reference = sr)

#iterate points and insert
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (outLnFc, "SHAPE@") as curs:
    for x1, y1 in pnts:
        for x2, y2 in pnts:
            #skip same points
            if (x1, y1) == (x2, y2):
                continue
            #create point array
            array = arcpy.Array ([arcpy.Point (x1, y1),
                                  arcpy.Point (x2, y2)])
            #create line feature
            line = arcpy.Geometry ("POLYLINE", array, sr)
            curs.insertRow ((line,))

#delete duplicates
shpFld = arcpy.Describe (outLnFc).shapeFieldName
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management (outLnFc, shpFld)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I ll try it now and i ll let you know.

Comment: It worked! I' m really gratefull! I didnt delete the duplicates as i need the lines for routing(walking).